# Is there any purpose to source degeneration in a Common Source amplifier with acurrent mirror biasing

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, analog

Say you have a cute Common Source amplifier and you have biased it through an NMOS Current Mirror connected to the source.

[image]

The current mirror sets \$I_D\$ to a fixed value and consequently, \$V_{GS}\$, meaning the circuit is more stable and won't suffer from \$V_{GS}\$ variations.

Another way to do so is by using a a source degeneration resistor which regulates \$V_{GS}\$ albeit not as well as the current mirror method.

What about combining both? Does that make a difference? Would the circuit be more stable? Is \$R_{SS}\$ redundant at this point?

I've seen the methods presented separately in a few books but I can't find examples of what I did anywhere.

Speaking of redundancy, I've read that \$R_G\$ is there to protect the MOSFET from parasitic currents and more. Is \$R_G\$ even needed in a simulation circuit? Does it serve any other job other than providing protection?

Thank you!

Comment: Source degeneration will be useful if you place resistor Rss_L in series with capacitor Css_L.

Comment: @S.s. hmm do you mean in series in the branch where \$C_{ss}\$ is? Or connect the cap in series with the resistor in the branch connected to drain? If the latter, wouldn't that block DC, and as such the current bias? Thank you!

Comment: Connect the resistor in series in the branch where Css is, meaning, just put the resistor from the capacitor to ground.

Comment: The 1.62k resistor in the source doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @KevinWhite yea it does seem like it. Idk why it took me so long to get it but I was staring it and thinking "if \$V_{GS}\$ is constant due to the source, then \$R_{SS}\$ isn't doing anything

Comment: @S.s. I see. Well that gave me chance to decrease my 3dB point but it killed the gain. I'm analyzing it right now trying to understand what's going on

Comment: @S.s.so basically after doing a small-signal analysis, the gain becomes a much more complicated term and it went all the way down -0.7dB. Interesting

Comment: @KevinKZ the whole concept of degeneration is that it lowers the gain in exchange for linearity, so nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @S.s.absolutely. I realized biasing with the current source is the best route and having that Rs resistor connected to the Cs capacitor wouldn't do much good. There's a common drain amplifier connected to the CS so I was able to use the CD's bias resistors to set the gain I wanted. Thanks for the help!